# UITableViewCell Segue not Working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making an app where I have a UITableView that the user adds data to, and I want the user to be able to tap on the cell and see more details about the cell they chose. I set up a segue from the cell to my cellDetailController where I will later add all the details of the cell they chose. When I run the app and try to tap on the cell to segue, it just selects the cell and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here? Here is my storyboard set up:

(I cant upload pictures yet so here's a link)
http://tinypic.com/r/2ivcwsj/8

Heres the code for my the class connected to my tableView:

```
import UIKit

typealias eventTuple = (name: String, date: String)

var eventList : [eventTuple] = []

    class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var eventTable: UITableView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }

        override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
            eventTable.reloadData()


        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        // MARK: - Table view data source



        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
            // Return the number of rows in the section.
            return eventList.count
        }


        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

            cell.textLabel?.text = eventList[indexPath.row].name
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = eventList[indexPath.row].date

            return cell
        }



        /*
        // Override to support editing the table view.
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            if editingStyle == .Delete {
                // Delete the row from the data source
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
                // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
            }    
        }
        */

        /*
        // Override to support rearranging the table view.
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        }
        */

        /*
        // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
            // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
            return true
        }
        */


        // MARK: - Navigation

        // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
        override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if(segue.identifier == "showDetailSegue") {

            }     
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drag the segue from the tableViewController (the yellow icon on the top of the viewController), not from the tableCell. Then give that segue an identifier.

Override `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and perform the segue here via `performSegueWithIdentifier()`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // pass any object as parameter, i.e. the tapped row
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailSegue", sender: indexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: "not from the tableCell" but why ? I see it is also working .

Comment: Connecting to the cell via the selection segue is a valid way to do it too. Depends on what you want. If you do connect it to the cell directly, you shouldn't also call `performSegue` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Both have the same result. You are able to connect it from the cell or the view. This is even done in an official apple tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementEditAndDeleteBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH9-SW1

Answer (score 0):

It should not be necessary to override `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to achieve this functionality. See Apple's [Working with Table Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementEditAndDeleteBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH9-SW1). I ran into this same problem but it was due to an error in the TableViewController. The culprit was in one of the `tableView` methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`
```

If you're using a custom `UITableViewCell` class, then `tableView()` should return an instance of your custom class. In my case, I forgot to downcast the value returned from `dequeueReusableCell()` within this method. The call to `dequeueReusableCell()` should look something like this:

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell  else {
    fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of CustomTableViewCell.")
}
```