# prepare for segue call before tableView didSelectRowAt indexPath iOS

Tags: ios, unwind-segue

I have 3 VC - VC1, VC2 & VC3

I'm creating an unwind segue where -

1. VC1 is destination
2. VC2 is source

So, I've add Marker function in VC1 -

```
@IBAction func unwindToHomeViewController(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

and in VC2 I've created two variable -

```
var userSelectedPlacesLatitude: Double = 0
var userSelectedPlacesLongitude: Double = 0
```

which will be updated in tableView -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.userSelectedPlacesLatitude = suggestedPlacenames[indexPath.row].geometry.coordinates[1]
    self.userSelectedPlacesLongitude = suggestedPlacenames[indexPath.row].geometry.coordinates[0]
    print("In didSelectRowAt", userSelectedPlacesLatitude, userSelectedPlacesLongitude)
}
```

and then prepare for segue -

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! VC1
    print("In Segue preperation",userSelectedPlacesLatitude, userSelectedPlacesLongitude)
    destinationVC.userSelectedPlacesLatitude = self.userSelectedPlacesLatitude
    destinationVC.userSelectedPlacesLongitude = self.userSelectedPlacesLongitude
    destinationVC.reloadWeatherDataStatus = true
}
```

But from print value I'm seeing that **prepareforSegue** is called earlier than **didSelectRowAt.** Hence I'm not getting expected value in **prepareforsugue**

```
In Segue preperation 0.0 0.0
In didSelectRowAt 49.3227937844972 31.3202829593814
```

Hence `0.0 0.0` is passing all the time to VC1. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: In your Storyboard, you connected the segue from the cell of VC1 to the VC2. So it will be trigger on cell selection BEFORE the didSelect delegate method is called. Instead, remove the segue, and redo it, but from VC1 to VC2 this time.

Comment: that means I've to switch the marker function from VC1 to VC2?

Comment: No. You created in your storyboard a segue. Your start point (in your dragging) was from a cell. Instead, start from VC1. (on the little bar above it, start from there). Then, you should also call manually `performSegue()` in `didSelect`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820580/uitableviewcell-segue-not-working

Comment: As well as fixing your segue so that it is triggered manually, I would suggest that you actually have the location properties on VC2. Then, in the unwind IBAction function you can use the provided segue to access the source VC instance and get the properties. Then VC2 doesn't need to know anything about VC 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing results from having at the unwind segue linked directly from the table view cell in your storyboard.  As soon as the user taps the row, the unwind segue fires.  The `didSelectRow(at:)` function is called after, but this is too late; You are already back in VC1.

While you can use `prepareForSegue` to send data *to* VC1, a better approach is to use the `sender` passed to `unwindToHomeViewController` to let VC1 get the data *from* VC2.

This means that VC2 doesn't need to know anything about VC1.  You can also get rid of the `reloadWeatherDataStatus` property and simply reload the weather data status in the unwind function.

You should:

- Remove the segue from the table view row in VC2
- In your storyboard, ctrl-drag from the "View controller" icon at the top of VC2 to the "Exit" icon at the top of VC2 and select `unwindToHomeViewController`
- Select the newly created unwind segue and give it an identifier, say `unwindToVC1`
- In VC2 you have

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.userSelectedPlacesLatitude = suggestedPlacenames[indexPath.row].geometry.coordinates[1]
    self.userSelectedPlacesLongitude = suggestedPlacenames[indexPath.row].geometry.coordinates[0]
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"unwindToVC1", sender: self)
}
```

- Remove `prepare(for segue: sender:)` from VC2
- In VC1

```
@IBAction func unwindToHomeViewController(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceVC = sender.source as? VC2 {
        self.userSelectedPlacesLatitude = sourceVC.userSelectedPlacesLatitude
        self.userSelectedPlacesLongitude = sourceVC.userSelectedPlacesLongitude
        // Do whatever is required to reload the data based on the new location
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below and let me know if it works -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let destinationVC = VC1()
    destinationVC.userSelectedPlacesLatitude = suggestedPlacenames[indexPath.row].geometry.coordinates[1]
    destinationVC.userSelectedPlacesLongitude = suggestedPlacenames[indexPath.row].geometry.coordinates[0]
    destinationVC.reloadWeatherDataStatus = true
    destinationVC.performSegueWithIdentifier("DestinationSegueName", sender: self)
}
```

Adding modifications to this answer since some people might have problems with creating the VC instance -

Step 1 - Create a manual segue named "SegueToDestinationVc" from source(VC1) to destination(VC2) view controller and write this code in source view controller -

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "SegueToDestinationVc") {
        let vc = segue.destination as! VC2
        vc.dataToPass = someData
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    someData = placeName[indexPath.row]
}
```

Step 2 - In destination view controller(VC2) has a public property named "dataToPass" and use it.

Happy to help, Thanks.

Happy Coding

Let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: As we are creating a new object of VC! in 2nd line `let destinationVC = VC1()` the value in the VC1 is not updating

Comment: I've to change the variables static then updated these variables in didSelectRowAt method

Comment: Yes but you need to remove the prepareforSegue code so that it creates a new VC object, assign the values and perform the segue. The prepareforSegue code is redundant now.

Comment: This code is just wrong.  First it creates a view controller instance without using the storyboard and which isn't in the view controller hierarchy and then uses that to trigger a segue.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have updated my answer to fit your comments.